# How to programmatically access window(global) object in content script in firefox 52?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

How to programmatically access window(global) object in content script in firefox 52?

`window["myGlobalObjectName"]`is not work in this content script case.

Seem all `user-defined-object-name`is not one member of `window` in this case.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "description": "word_extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "word_extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "word_extension@myself.myself",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  },
   "permissions": ["<all_urls>","tabs","nativeMessaging"],
  "content_scripts":[{
"matches":["<all_urls>"]
      ,"run_at":"document_idle","js":["content_script.js"]}]
}
```

content_script.js:

```
var test=123
function f()
{
    console.log("hello")
}

//All of the following is undefined
console.log(window.f)
console.log(window.test)
console.log(window["f"])
console.log(window["test"])
```

Comment: Show us the code where they are declared, preferable as a working code snippet reproducing the issue you describe

Comment: @LGSon example code is done,thank you for point out defect of this question.